# less.watch for JS files

Tags: javascript, less, development-environment

Is it possible to reload js files client-side when they are changed, as it can be seen in the less watch mode feature ([enter link description here](http://lesscss.org/) -> Watch Mode).

Unfortunately I don't know how the watch mode works and why it could or wouldn't be possible for JS files.

Comment: You can live-edit your JS in the Chrome inspector if you just want to debug something. Dynamically reloading JS wouldn't work well for any number of reasons.

Comment: There must be a way to achieve it. The meteor framework (meteor.com) is able to do it well. Watch the screencast.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why wouldn't you just press Ctrl+R or F5, but you can update the `src` attributes, using jQuery:

```
$('script').each(function () {
    $(this).attr('src', $(this).attr('src'));
});
```

This should make them reload. Put this in `setInterval`/`requestAnimationFrame`. I hope this is for testing only.

Comment: @Erik I've misspelled function's name. It's `each`, not `forEach` as I wrote. Fixed while ago.

Comment: I know :) I fixed it but still ... changed code is not applied. Maybe it's one of the "any reasons" @Mathletcs mentioned?